# Git integration with Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am creating a Jenkins pipeline.

But in pipeline when I select Git and give repository it gives me following error

> Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command: git ls-remote -h 
>    https://github.com/trushant-dw/aushitosh.git HEAD

I have added my git credentials in gobal credentials but not sure still why it's throwing this error.

Below is my pipeline

```
node {
    stage 'Checkout'
        git 'git@github.com:trushant-dw/dockerwebapp.git'
    stage 'Docker build'
        docker.build('demo-docker')
    stage 'Docker push'
        docker.withRegistry('https://944198216610.dkr.ecr.us-east- 
        1.amazonaws.com', 'ecr:us-east-1:demo-ecr-credentials') {
            docker.image('demo').push('latest')
        }
}
```

Comment: Please post a sample of your pipeline.

Comment: @Dibakar Added pipline in original post

Answer (score 0):

I installed git in my jenkins server.

```sh
$ yum install git
$ which git
  /usr/lib/git
```

And then in Manage Jenkins ---> Global config tools ----> Git i have added the path.It worked for me.